# Md-list in md-card is not adjusting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

The `md-list` in `md-card` is not adjusting to different screen sizes, in spite of the `flex` attribute. I believe it might be because of the `ng-href` inside of the `md-list-item`.

This is the setup that I have:

```html
<md-content layout="row" layout-align="space-around stretch">
    <md-content layout="column" layout-align="start stretch" flex="90">
        <div></div>
    </md-content>

    <md-content flex>
        <md-card>
            <md-card-content>
                <md-list>
                    <md-list-item ng-href="" ng-repeat="">
                        <md-icon></md-icon>
                        <p></p>
                    </md-list-item>
                </md-list>
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
    </md-content>
</md-content>
```

Comment: Why are you using and `md-content` inside of another `md-content`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You code snippet is right, let me give you some specification :**

**The md-list-item component automatically detects if the list item should be clickable.**

**If the md-list-item is clickable, we wrap all content inside of a**  and create an overlaying button, which will will execute the given actions (like ng-href, ng-click)

We create an overlaying button, instead of wrapping all content inside of the button, because otherwise some elements may not be clickable inside of the button.

When using a secondary item inside of your list item, the md-list-item component will automatically create a secondary container at the end of the md-list-item, which contains all secondary items.

The secondary item container is not static, because otherwise the overflow will not work properly on the list item.

Here is the example form official site of material angular :

```
 <md-list>
  <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="item in allTask">
    <md-checkbox ng-model="item.done"></md-checkbox>
    <div class="md-list-item-text">
      <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
      <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```